# jQuery UI Tooltip - Showing Inline Content

Tags: jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm having trouble displaying hidden inline content within a jQuery UI tooltip widget. Here's what I have so far:

```
$("a.tooltip").tooltip({
        content: function() {
                $('table').show();
                return $('table');              
        }

    });
```

The table in question is set to not display by default. The above code shows the table in the tooltip, however, if I hover off the link that activates the tooltip, and return to it, an empty tooltip displays, without my inline content. I suspect I want to invoke the destroy() method when mousing off the tooltip, but not sure where to put that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to rebind the content

```
$("a.tooltip").on('mouseenter', '.sourceItem', function(){
    $(this).find('.table').show();              
    }).on('mouseleave', '.sourceItem', function(){
    $('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

use jQuery which uses on functionality.place this in the ready event.